# Can I determine if Ruby code is executing in a Sidekiq job?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

Can I do something like the following? If yes, how do I implement `in_sidekiq_job`?

```
def method_for_anyone_to_call
  if in_sidekiq_job
    puts "hey! I'm running in a Sidekiq job."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Sidekiq.server?` for that, i.e.:

```
def method_for_anyone_to_call
  if Sidekiq.server?
    puts "hey! I'm running in a Sidekiq job."
  end
end
```